# Prove that $\exists \{c_n\}$ monotonically increasing to $\infty$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_nc_n$ coverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given a real positive sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ converges.

Prove that there exists a real sequence $\{c_n\}$ monotonically increasing to $\infty$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_nc_n$ converges.

What I have done:

I have written
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}a_ic_i=c_{N+1}\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}a_i-\sum_{i=1}^N(c_{n+1}-c_n)S_n$$

and then try to prove the convergence by the Cauchy criterion. However my evaluation is still not good enough. I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $\displaystyle R_n=\sum_{k\geq n} a_k$. Then $R_n>0$, and $R_n$ decrease to $0$ as $n\to +\infty$. We show that $\displaystyle c_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R_n}}$ (obviously increasing to $+\infty$) do the job.

We have:
$$a_n c_n=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{R_n}}=\frac{R_n-R_{n+1}}{\sqrt{R_n}}\leq \int_{R_{n+1}}^{R_n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Hence for $N \geq 1$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n c_n \leq \int_{R_{N+1}}^{R_1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\leq \int_0^{R_1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}<+\infty$$
Hence $\sum a_n c_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Neat.  So it suffices to define $c_n=f(R_n)$ where $f$ is positive and monotone decreasing, $\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0}f(x)=+\infty$, and $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx<\infty$ (ignoring finitely many terms if needed).  In this answer $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$; my answer is analogous to taking $f(x) = -\log(x)$.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative approach.  There is a sequence of positive integers $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$ such that $\sum_{n=n_k}^\infty a_n < 2^{-k}$.  Define $c_n = k$ when $n_k\leq n<n_{k+1}$ (with $n_0=1$).  Then $c_n\nearrow+\infty$ and

$$\sum_n a_nc_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1}a_nc_n\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty k2^{-k}<\infty.$$

Comment: thanks for such a natural solution!