# If $\sum a_n<\infty$ then $\exists (b_n)$

Tags: analysis

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ and $a_n>0$, then $\exists (b_n)$ such that $b_n\geq1$, $b_n\to+\infty$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n<\infty$.

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/884782/

Answer (score 2):

Let $(r_n)$ the remainder of the  series i.e.

$$r_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_k$$
so since the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent then the sequence $(r_n)$ is convergent decreasing to $0$. We have

$$\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_{n-1}}}=\frac{r_{n-1}-r_n}{\sqrt{r_{n-1}}}=\frac{(\sqrt{r_{n-1}}-\sqrt{r_{n}})(\sqrt{r_{n-1}}+\sqrt{r_{n}})}{\sqrt{r_{n-1}}}<2(\sqrt{r_{n-1}}-\sqrt{r_{n}})$$ so by telescoping  we see that the series $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent with $$b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_{n-1}}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$$

Comment: Thanks! @Sami Ben Romdhane

Answer (score -1):

Yes. consider function $f(z) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_nz^n$. obviously $f$ is 
defined on entire $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\ | \ |z| \leq 1\}$. So for some 
$\epsilon > 0$ it can be defined on 
$\{z\in \mathbb{C}\ | \ |z| < 1+\epsilon\}$. 
This means that letting $b_n = (1+\frac{\epsilon}{2})^n$ can provide what you are 
looking for.

Comment: This is incorrect.  It does not follow that you can extend.

Comment: Can you tell me which is incorrect? $f$ is analytic on entire $D$ so for any point as $z \in\partial D$ there exists an $s_z > 0$ such that $f$ is analytic on $N_s(z)$ but $\partial D$ is compact and minimum of such $s$ exists. What's wrong?

Comment: It is wrong to assume that a neighborhood exists for each point on the boundary where the function can be extended analytically.  E.g. this fails for $\sum 1/n^2$.  In that case $|f'(r)|\to+\infty$ as $r\nearrow 1$, showing that $f$ is not analytic in any neigborhood of $1$.  It is also easy to verify independently that if $1/a_n$ has polynomial growth and $b_n$ has exponential growth, then $b_n a_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok. you're right. Thanks.